# Custom mongodb command in golang using gopkg.in/mgo.v2 as string

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I was wondering, is there anyway to run my own command (or query) which I have constructed as a string variable using "mgo" in go.

Something like this:

```
c := session.DB(DBNAME).C(COLLECTION)
c.RUN_COMMAND_AS_STRING("find({username:'vahid'})")
```

Comment: No there is no way of doing that To create a dynamic query use `bson` and pass that in a function returning the collection.

Comment: Thats a shame. But tnx @Himanshu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there anyway to run my own command (or query) which I have constructed as a string variable using "mgo" in go.

You can invoke [MongoDB find command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/find/), and parsing string of query filter to `map[string]interface{}`.

For example:

```
db := session.DB("databaseName")

queryString := `{"username":"sergio"}`
var filter map[string]interface{} 
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(queryString), &filter)

result := bson.M{}
err = db.Run(bson.D{{"find", "collectionName"}, {"filter", filter}}, &result)
fmt.Println(result)
```

Alternatively, instead of using `find()`, depending on your use case, you can also use [MongoDB Aggregation Pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/).

For example:

```
pipeString := `[{"$match":{"username":"sergio"}}, {"$project":{"newfield":"$username"}}]`

pipe := []bson.M{}
err = json.Unmarshal([]byte(pipeString), &pipe)

coll := session.DB("databaseName").C("collectionName")
response := []bson.M{}
err = coll.Pipe(pipe).All(&response)  
fmt.Println(response)
```

Comment: To anyone who is going to use this later. First of all, thanks for the reply. But it has been a long time ago when I was working on that project, at the moment I don't remember how I could go around the problem, but if the string in pipeString could be much more complicated than your example and it works In my opinion that means this is the correct answer for the problem. Overall I feel its a correct answer. Please let me know if anyone tried it and it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I like to use:

```
func dbInsert(collection string, insert bson.M, session *mgo.Session) error {
    c := session.DB(your_DB).C(collection)
    err := c.Insert(insert)
    return err
}

func dbUpsert(collection string, selector bson.M, update bson.M, session *mgo.Session) (*mgo.ChangeInfo, error) {
    c := session.DB(your_DB).C(collection)
    info, err := c.Upsert(selector, update)
    return info, err
}

func dbFindOne(collection string, findBson bson.M, selectBson bson.M, session *mgo.Session) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    c := session.DB(your_DB).C(collection)
    getMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := c.Find(findBson).Select(selectBson).One(&getMap)
    return getMap, err
}

func dbFindAll(collection string, findBson bson.M, selectBson bson.M, session *mgo.Session) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    c := session.DB(your_DB).C(collection)
    getMap := make(map[string]interface{})
    err := c.Find(findBson).Select(selectBson).All(&getMap)
    return getMap, err
}

func dbUpdate(collection string, selector bson.M, update bson.M, session *mgo.Session) error {
    c := session.DB(your_DB).C(collection)
    setBson := bson.M{};
    setBson["$set"] = update;
    //
    updateError := c.Update(selector, setBson)
    //
    return updateError
}

func dbRemoveOne(collection string, selector bson.M, session *mgo.Session) error {
    c := session.DB(your_DB).C(collection)
    removeError := c.Remove(selector)
    return removeError
}

func dbRemoveAll(collection string, selector bson.M, session *mgo.Session) (*mgo.ChangeInfo, error) {
    c := session.DB(your_DB).C(collection)
    removeInfo, removeError := c.RemoveAll(selector)
    return removeInfo, removeError
}
```

Here's a sample query for find:

```
//FIND ONE:
employeeInfo, err := dbFindOne("employees", bson.M{"name": "john"}, bson.M{"salary": 1, "homeCity": 1}, mongo_session)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error getting employee info: ", err)
}else{
    //you can get the salary as an int:
    salary := employeeInfo["salary"].(int)

    //or get their homeCity as a string:
    homeCity := employeeInfo["homeCity"].(string)
}
```

This for instance finds the "salary" of employee named "john" in the collection "employees".

All the methods in the snippet work in almost the same exact way as `dbFindOne()`.

Hope this helps!